# Phaser 3: Allow Particles to emit with flipped/mirrored image?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, particles

I have a particle emitter which emits multiple duplicates of the same image, as usual. However I'd like some of the particles to be flipped, either completely at a random amount, or sort of in the middle, so that particles falling to the left would be flipped and particles falling to the right won't be.

However I couldn't find anything regarding flipping particles without flipping ALL of them. I'd only like some to be flipped. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @mplungjan if you have an issue with my question, please explain what your issue with it is. From what I can see in the links you've shown, my question adheres to all the rules and recommendation.

Comment: @mplungjan If that was your issue, why not say so? NONE of the links you provided speak about code, aside from, "Explain your problem before providing code." Nowhere it is mentioned that code is required. Besides, from reading my question it is obvious that code is relatively irrelevant, considering that I am LOOKING for the code to produce what I am trying to achieve. Before I can write code, I need to know how.
Nevertheless, I suppose I can add the code of my regular particle, if that makes you happy.

Comment: @mplungjan Again, the code is relatively irrelevant to my question. Not every single question about programming requires you to post pre-existing code, thus it is not a standard requirenment. I appreciate the help, but telling me to visit sites I've visited before and followed correctly, is not helpful. If you believe that code is relevant in this example specifically, gladly tell me so. But that is not what you did.

Comment: @alex your question was, clear without the code _(some questions are, like this one)_, sometimes some people just get carried away. It is all good. :)

Comment: as a japanese curler wrote _Let's just have fun_ https://i.insider.com/62101895f0b06900185ea9f9?width=1000&format=jpeg&auto=webp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are serveral way's, I think the "fastest" would be just to use the `scaleX` property of the emiter.

> this code flips *about* 10% of the particles `( 0.9 > Math.random() )`, through multiplying it with `-1`, when it should be flipped.

**Example Code:**

```
this.add.particles('sparkle').createEmitter({
    x: 200,
    y: 100,
    scaleX: {
        onEmit: function () { 
            return ( 0.9 > Math.random() ) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    },
    speed: { min: -100, max: 100 },
    quantity: 0.1,
    frequency: 1,
});
```

But I assume from a earlier question, that you have emitter with a *"random scale"* property. I that case you woud have to do something like this:

**Example Code, for random scaled particles:**

```
gameState.splash = this.add.particles('droplet').createEmitter({
    x: gameState.height/2,
    y: gameState.width/2,
    scale:  { 
        onEmit: function () {
            // create random new scale
            let newRandowmScale = Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.05, 0.3);
            return ( 0.9 > Math.random() ) ? -1 * newRandowmScale  : newRandowmScale;
         }
    },
    speed: { min: -100, max: 100 },
    ...
});
```

**UPDATE(SlowerFix): Example Code, for random scaled particles:**

> ***What the update does:*** save the current scale of the `scaleX` event and use it in the `scaleY` event. *(it is hacky, but should work. I will see if there is a cleaner solution)*

```
gameState.splash = this.add.particles('droplet').createEmitter({
    x: gameState.height/2,
    y: gameState.width/2,
    scaleY:{
        onEmit: function(particle){
            // keep scale value positive
            return Math.abs(particle.scaleX);
        }
    },
    scaleX:{
        onEmit: function(p){
            let scale = Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(.2, .5);
            return Math.random() > .9 ? scale * -1 : scale;
        }
    }, 
    speed: { min: -100, max: 100 },
    ...
});
```

Comment: I have one more followup question though, if that is alright! The second code example (random scaled particles) works best for my case! However, it seems to flip the image both vertically and horizontally. Is something like that possible, while only flipping vertically?

Comment: @alex I updated my answer, but I will post a better solution soon. _(I hope)_

Comment: Thank you so much! Using your solution gave me the error that emitter._currentScale wasn't defined, however changing emitter to particle fixed that! (Or alternatively, changing the particle parameter to emitter) This seems to work perfectly so far :D If you do find a better solution, I'd love to see it, but I'm happy as long as it works :)

Comment: @alex,I updated the version again. I couldn't get the frame version to work, but this version, is okay and has _less moving parts._